# Storing additional information about customer in Shopify

Tags: shopify

I'm creating a website for travel deals on Shopify. The user would need to enter information such as name and age for every person on the order, as well as passport info. Is there a way I can ask the user to enter that info after their purchase, essentially updating their purchase info? This way a user won't have to have his/her passport number in order to purchase.

Cheers,

Dean

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by linking to a form in the order confirmation email. You can edit this template on the 'Email & Notifications' preferences page in the admin.

The simplest option for the form itself would be to use Google Docs, but there are other services that provide a more professional look and feel. [Wufoo](http://wufoo.com/) is a good example.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a tiny app to upload this info to the customer database using [metafields](http://docs.shopify.com/api/metafield). Depending on where and how you want this info collected David option is ok, though you should also consider placing this tiny app/form in the Thankyou page, using the [Additional Content & Scripts form](http://docs.shopify.com/support/configuration/store-customization/legacy-checkout/how-do-i-customize-my-thank-you-page).